# How to acess the object inside the nested array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I have an array called data which is fetching the data as a form of nested array. Its structure looks like this.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#3 ▼
      +"id": "8"
      +"title": "Accounting"
      +"type": {
               +"id": "18"
                +"title": "BookKeeping"
           }
}
    1 => {#3 ▼
      +"id": "10"
      +"title": "Accounting"
      +"type": {
               +"id": "20"
                +"title": "Balancesheet"}
}
]
]
```

This is the data that I am getting in the form of a nested array. I need to find a maximum id i.e. 10 so that I can get the associated  type title based on the max id. I tried in several ways by using array helpers, and using foreach loop but could not succeed.Any kind of help and support is appreciated. Hope to get a positive rep

Comment: I'm not a laravel person, but if you just want the max entry, this is something you could do when selecting the information

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach.

```
$array = <your array variable>;
$max = 0;
foreach($array as $value) if($value['id'] > $max) $max = $value['id'];
```

or if you want get key of this variable

```
$array = <your array variable>;
$max = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) if($value['id'] > $max) $max = $key;
```

or if your array is in ascending order you can just get your last elements' id like this:

```
 $array = <your array variable>;
 $max = array_pop($array)['id'];
```

note: but if you use array_pop you lost last element - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php
and there is way to not lost

```
 $array = <your array variable>;
 $max = end($array)['id'];
```

Comment: If it doesn't help please comment for more information